# Escaping characters behave differently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

PFB the code snippet and it compiles to `<div data-value="{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Within" a="" month"}="">Within a month</div>`. How can I make it work correctly using JavaScript?

```js
var a = JSON.stringify({"name": "Within a month"});
document.body.innerHTML = '<div data-value=' + a + '>Within a month</div>';
```

Comment: Define "correctly"; what out put would you want? What you're showing looks correct to me.

Comment: I think I see - there's a quotation inserted after within. If you query the `dataset` for the `value` field, it is `"{"name":"Within"` instead of the full string.

Answer (score 0):

Decode your string as follows.

```js
var parser = new DOMParser;
var decodedValue = parser.parseFromString("{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Within&quot;}", 'text/html').body.textContent;
console.log(decodedValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need additional wrapping quotes after `data-value` - try this instead:

```
var a = JSON.stringify({"name": "Within a month"});
document.body.innerHTML = '<div data-value=\'' + a + '\'>Within a month</div>';
```